# Why will my body not accept my margins?

Tags: html, css

I am building a site for my school's robotics team. This is my first time ever coding in html/css. For some reason, my other pages use the margins quite nicely, but for this page specifically, my "margin-right" element does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Team 3774 Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
<div class="Banner">
<a class="Banner_Link" href="www.robotichive3774.com">
<img src="/Images/Banner.png" height="200" width="1350" border="0">
</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="Team_Bio">
 <div class="example">
  <h2>Team Bio</h2>
   <h1>Example</h1>
    <ul>
     <li class="li_info">Class</li>
     <li class="li_info">Role</li>
     <li class="li_info">Career Interests</li>
     <li class="li_info">Other Clubs and Sports</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="Abanoub_Boules">
    <div class="info_AB">
        <h1>Abanoub Boules</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Captian, Coder, Documenter</li> 
        <li class="li_info">CEO of a Biology Firm</li>
        <li class="li_info">Coptic Society</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        <li class="li_info">President of Stem Clubs</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="picture_AB">
    <img src="Abanoub.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
   </div>
  </div>



<div class="Andre_Bernardo">
    <div class="info_ABe">
        <h1>Andre Bernardo</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, 3D modeling</li>
        <li class="li_info">Computer Science</li>
        <li class="li_info">Tennis</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_ABe">
        <img src="Andre.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
   </div>


<div class="Leo_Scarano">
    <div class="info_LS">
        <h1>Leo Scarano</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Coder</li>
        <li class="li_info">Computer Science</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_LS">
        <img src="Leo.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Mina_Hanna">
    <div class="info_MH">   
        <h1>Mina Hanna</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Coder</li>
        <li class="li_info">Pharmaceutics</li>
        <li class="li_info">Coptic Society</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_MH">
        <img src="Mina.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Kenneth_Rebbecke">
    <div class="info_KR">   
        <h1>Kenneth Rebbecke</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Documenter</li>
        <li class="li_info">Structual Engineering</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_KR">
        <img src="Kenny.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Kristen_Kaldas">
    <div class="info_KK">
        <h1>Kristen Kaldas</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Coder, Bookkeeper</li>
        <li class="li_info">Biomedical Engineering</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Seminar</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Club</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_KK">
        <img src="Kristen.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Melanie_Aguilar">
    <div class="info_MA">
        <h1>Melanie Aguilar</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Secratary, Mascot</li>
        <li class="li_info">Party Planner</li>
        <li class="li_info">Yearbook</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_MA">
        <img src="Melanie.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="Anish_Patel">
    <div class="info_AP">
        <h1>Anish Patel</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Junior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, 3d modeling</li>
        <li class="li_info">Mechanical Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Club</li>
        <li class="li_info">Junior Classical League</li>
        <li class="li_info">Certamn</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_AP">
        <img src="Anish.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Furhan_Ashraf">
    <div class="info_FA">   
        <h1>Furhan Ashraf</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Junior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Financial Advisor, Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineering/Undecided</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Club</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_FA">
        <img src="Furhan.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Andrew_W">
    <div class="info_AW">
        <h1>Andrew Wojtkowski</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, 3d Modeling</li>
        <li class="li_info">Aerospace Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Varsity Hockey</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_AW">
        <img src="Andrew.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Bryan_F">
    <div class="info_BF">
        <h1>Bryan Ferreira</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Documenter</li>
        <li class="li_info">Computer Engineer/Civil Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Guitar</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_BF">
        <img src="Bryan.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
</div>



 </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.Team_Bio
{
margin-left: 200px;
margin-right: 200px;
}



a.Banner_Link
 {
  padding:0 !important;
 }

 .Banner
{
height: 200px;
width: 1350px;
}



#page{
width: 1000px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
}

div
{
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.body
{
margin-left: 200px;
margin-right: 200px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.Banner img 
{
vertical-align:top;
}

body
{
margin: 0;
}


.li_nav
{
float: left;
display:inline-block;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.nav 
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; 
min-width: 1350px;  
}

a:link, a:visited 
{
display:inline-block;
width: 182.7px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #990000;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

a:hover, a:active 
{
background-color: #B20000;
}

.Team_Bio
{
min-width: 1350px;
}

 h2 
{
 font-size: 60px;
 text-align: center;
}

 .example 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

 .Abanoub_Boules 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The site is robotichive3774.com if you want to see exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: Awful HTML & CSS. Where is your charset? Why uppercase & spaces for web paths? `width` & `height` HTML attributes have no unit. In CSS, `0` has no unit too, and there are some unused CSS. Learn more web authoring skills in MDN

Comment: which margin not work?

Comment: the .Team_Bio margin

Comment: @HiveVoltage That's what I thought it was. My question is, what is the purpose of the margin? You don't want the content to be right up against the edge of the page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. To be honest, I am thinking of just abandoning all of this and starting a new page using like bootstrap or foundation or something. Since I am not focusing on web development as a career, I do not see a point in writing in bare-bones HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, the HTML and CSS are a mess but as you said you're new to this.

The layout problem has to do with the widths of your team member sections inside that element. They're forcing it to stretch out.

I'd recode the CSS for the team members.

Start by removing the pixels widths on each team member's and set them to percentage based widths.

Make the team member's main element 100% wide so it just fills the container it's sitting in.

Then set their info and picture wrapping elements to 49% each.

Set the image inside the picture wrapping element to 100% and auto for the height.

Do all these widths etc in your CSS file.

That should fix you right up.

Lastly, if you're gonna do the floats put a "clearing div" after each team member so the next section if forced below the previous run. Otherwise things will run into each other.

Like this:

```
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear { clear: both; }
```

In the end, you should really simply your code. There's too many classes etc. All the team member sections could have the same class so you can apply global rules etc.